# Unable to ssh to Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have constructed an azure VM that has a Tomcat server running and a postgreSQL database.  I was able to ssh to it with no problem until this morning.  I can't find a roadmap to actually know what is needed for this to work, I suspect I have something wrong.  I could just delete the VM and start fresh, but I would learn nothing from that activity.  My dashboard has the following:

```
xxxVM            Virtual Machine
xxxSecurityGroup Network Security Group
xxxVMNet         Virtual Network
xxxVMVMNIC       Network Interface
xxxVMPublicIP    Public IP address
xxxVMNSG         Network Security Group
storage account
xxxVM_disk1      Disk
```

I think there could be a problem with having two Network Security Groups.  One has 1 subnet and 0 network interfaces and the other has 0 subnets and 1 network interface.  I have stopped the VM and want to delete the network security group that has the subnet and no network interface, but every time I attempt this, I get a message that the delete failed and the message content is cut off.  It tells me that the network security group is use but doesn't finish the error.

> Failed to delete network security group 'xxxSecurityGroup'.
>   Error: Network security group
>   /subscriptions/12345/resourceGroups/xxxResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/xxxSecurityGroup
>   cannot be deleted because it is in use by the following resources:
>   /subscriptions/12345/resourceGroups/xxxResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/vi

I have tried to stop anything I can but to no avail.  Any suggestions?

Comment: On the VM, not only do you have to stop it, but you have to _deallocate_ it. Check out this article (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gbanin/2015/04/22/difference-between-the-states-of-azure-virtual-machines-stopped-and-stopped-deallocated/) That should let you do any deleting of in-use resources if needed.

Comment: A few more things to check: Make sure your IP address didn't change on the networking interface. Port 22 should be allowed to the external internet through your network security group.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete the NSG while its in use. Technically the VM is not using the NSG so stopping the VM does nothing to release NSG.

Having 2 NSG is not an issue you just need to make sure they both have Port 22 open to allow SSH.

Hope this helps.